# What happens to a Python input value if it's not assigned to a variable?

Tags: python, input

Was just wondering this. So sometimes programmers will insert an `input()` into a block of code without assigning its value to anything for the purpose of making the program wait for an input before continuing. Usually when it runs, you're expected to just hit enter without typing anything to move forward, but what if you do type something? What happens to that string if its not assigned to any variable? Is there any way to read its value after the fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR: If you don't immediately assign the return value of `input()`, it's lost.

I can't imagine how *or why* you would want to retrieve it afterwards.

---

If you have any callable (as all callables have return values, default is `None`), call it and do not save its return value, there's no way to get that again. You have one chance to capture the return value, and if you miss it, it's gone.

The return *value* gets created inside the callable of course, the code that makes it gets run and some memory will be allocated to hold the value. Inside the callable, there's a variable name referencing the value (except if you're directly returning something, like `return "unicorns".upper()`. In that case there's of course no name).

But after the callable returns, what happens? The return value is still there and can be assigned to a variable name in the calling context. All names that referenced the value inside the callable are gone though. Now if you don't assign the value to a name in your call statement, there are no more names referencing it.

What does that mean? It's gets on the garbage collector's hit list and will be nuked from your memory on its next garbage collection cycle. Of course the GC implementation may be different for different Python interpreters, but the standard CPython implementation uses reference counting.

So to sum it up: if you don't assign the return value a name in your call statement, it's gone for your program and it will be destroyed and the memory it claims will be freed up any time afterwards, as soon as the GC handles it in background.

---

Now of course a callable might do other stuff with the value before it finally returns it and exits. There are a few possible ways how it could preserve a value:

- Write it to an existing, `global` variable
- Write it through any output method, e.g. store it in a file
- If it's an instance method of an object, it can also write it to the object's instance variables.

But what for? Unless there would be any benefit from storing the last return value(s), why should it be implemented to hog memory unnecessarily?

There are a few cases where caching the return values makes sense, i.e. for functions with determinable return values (means same input always results in same output) that are often called with the same arguments and take long to calculate.

But for the `input` function? It's probably the least determinable function existing, even if you call `random.random()` you can be more sure of the result than when you ask for user input. Caching makes absolutely no sense here.

Answer (score 0):

The value is discarded.  You can't get it back.  It's the same as if you just had a line like `2 + 2` or `random.rand()` by itself; the result is gone.